# is there away how to handle error 13 in vba

Tags: excel, vba

1. Hello

   I have an error 13 on my vlookup all the time ,when I execute vlookup on my sheet it works soon vba doesn't I am looking for help

here is my code , all the columns are Text  in my sheet

```
     Sub address_change()
     Dim updatesheet As Variant
     Dim sbw As String
     Dim Param As String
     Dim entier As Integer
     Dim fname As String
     Dim tsk As Task
     Dim rg As Variant
     Dim ws As Sheets
     Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
     Dim appXLS As Object
     Dim entxls As Object
     Dim i As Integer
     Set appXLS = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
     If appXLS Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox ("XLS not installed")
     End If
     fname = ActiveProject.Path & "\" & Dir(ActiveProject.Path & "\addresses.xlsx")
     MsgBox (fname)Set wb = appXLS.Workbooks.Open(fname, False)
     Set rg = appXLS.Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A:U")
     appXLS.Visible = TrueMsgBox (appXLS.Application.Value)


     On Error Resume Next

     For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks 
         Param = tsk.Text2
         If tsk.OutlineLevel = 2 Then
         updatesheet = appXLS.Application.VLookup(Param, rg, 16, False)
           If Err.Number <> 0 Then
             tsk.Text13 = "No match 32"
           Else
             tsk.Text13 = updatesheet
           End If

      End If
     Next tsk
    End Sub
```

Comment: A type missmatch usually happens when you try to set a variable to a different type, like text to an integer. Exactly what line is throwing the error?

Comment: First of all you need to remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line hides **all** error massages, but the errors still occur. You just cannot see their messages. If you don't see them you cannot fix them and your code does not work correctly. This line is **evil** if not used with full error handling (see [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)). Remove it and tell us in which line of code you get the error message.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to use the Excel `VLookup` (and similar functions like `Match`) with VBA, and they differ.

`Application.VLookup` (the version you are using) will *return* an error value  `Error 2042` if the search term cannot be found. This is **not** a runtime error, this is a return value. Error values are a special data type in VBA (they are not strings, the `Error 2042` is just the representation of it). To be precise, this error is the `#N/A` that you see in Excel if a Vlookup fails.

You write the result into variable `updatesheet`, that is fine as it is declared as `Variant`, and a variant can hold an error value. However, now you check if an error occurred and as this is not the case, it will try to assign the error value to `tsk.Text13` and this gives you a type mismatch error (I assume that `tsk.Text13` expects a string).

Instead of checking for a runtime error as you do, you need to check if `updatesheet` contains an error value, this is done using the `IsError`-function. In this case, you could also use the `Application.IsNA()`-function.

The alternative is to use `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup`, this will throw a runtime error if can't find the search term, and you need to wrap this into Error handling.

Use either the one or the other method:

```
updatesheet = appXLS.VLookup(Param, rg, 16, False)
If appXLS.IsNA(updatesheet) Then
    tsk.text13 = "No match 32"
Else
    tsk.text13 = updatesheet
End If

updatesheet = "No match 32"
On Error Resume Next
updatesheet = appXLS.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Param, rg, 16, False)
On Error GoTo 0
tsk.text13 = updatesheet
```

For further reading, I recommend https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2021/02/15/worksheetfunction-and-errors/