# Changing File name based on VLOOKUP using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to save sheets as a pdf and name the pdf with the sheet name and a region using a vlookup. My vlookup will not work and I cannot find the answer online. Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub ConvertSheetToPDFVlookup()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pdfFileName As String
Dim savePath As String
Dim previousMonth As String
Dim sheetName As String
Dim lookupValue As String
Dim lookupResult As String

' Get the name of the previous month
previousMonth = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Now), "mmm" & "-" & "yy")

' Create a new folder based on the previous month
savePath = "My desired location" & previousMonth & "\"

' Reference the active sheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

' Get the sheet name
sheetName = ws.Name

' Perform the VLOOKUP
lookupValue = sheetName
lookupResult = Application.VLookup(lookupValue, Sheets("ContractCode").Range("A1:B132"), 2, False)

' Generate PDF file name based on the sheet name and VLOOKUP result
pdfFileName = savePath & sheetName & " - " & lookupResult & ".pdf"

' Export the active sheet as PDF
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=pdfFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard

' Highlight the active sheet tab in green
ws.Tab.Color = RGB(144, 238, 144) ' Light Green

' Optional: Display a message when the process is complete
MsgBox "PDF conversion complete!" & vbCrLf & "PDF saved in: " & pdfFileName, vbInformation
End Sub
```

[Sheet Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF8ox.png)

[List of values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H5lU.png)

Comment: That should be `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`

Comment: What is the error, and the error message?

Comment: @CHill60 `Application.Vlookup` is the late-bound version and is perfectly fine, and maybe even preferable to `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup`.

Comment: What value does the function return? or does it even return anything?

Comment: @Blackcat I get a runtime error 13, type mismatch and then the debug will highlight the lookupResult line of code. I think it's referring to the vlookup not working, my list in on a sheet named ContractCodes in the same file

Comment: When you get a type mismatch, the VLookup coudn't find the value and returned an Error (Error 2042). An Error is incompatible with a string (you cannot assign the error to a string variable). That means your lookup-table in sheet "ContractCode" doesn't contain an entry for the ActiveSheet.

Comment: Most likely your lookupValue is not in your list. When you get to the error try some debugging steps: click on the cell in your list that you think should be the match, and in the immediate window type `?lookupvalue`, `?activecell`, and `?activecell = lookupvalue`

Comment: You get the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31735588/20643658)

Comment: @Blackcat I have declared the lookup result as a variant and used the worksheet.function  and now I get a 1004 run time error, unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheet.function class

Comment: Yes we are on the right track.  If not found by VLOOKUP an error is generated. The difference is that Application.Vlookup returns an `error value` , while Worksheetfunction invokes an error in VBA. To resolve this issue somehow need to handle the error according to the qualifier.

Comment: I notice your comment says "ContractCodes" but your code says `Sheets("ContractCode")` - do you have 2 different sheets with these 2 different names?

Comment: Appreciate the response but I'm not sure what you mean by your last sentence

Comment: @kevin The sheet name and the name of the sheet in the code match exactly. I was just playing with changing the sheet name to see if made any difference

Comment: Pls. have a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69627978/20643658) by [FunThomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7599798/funthomas)

Comment: @BigBen - thanks for that heads up. I'll go read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but it gets too complicated for comments...

When you get a Type mismatch error when you assign something to a string variable, that means the value cannot be stored as a String. As VBA is rather generous, it will try to convert nearly anything to a string *except* for error values. So I strongly assume that `Vlookup` couldn't find the value and returned an error. You can easily prove that by changing the variable type to Variant and check what was returned, eg

```
Dim lookupResult As Variant
lookupResult = Application.VLookup(lookupValue, Sheets("ContractCode").Range("A1:B132"), 2, False)
If IsError(lookupResult) Then
    MsgBox "Vlookup was not able to find a value for [" + lookupValue & "]" & vbCrLf _
         & "Instead, it returned an error: " & CStr(lookupResult)
End If
```

Using a Variant will prevent the Type mismatch runtime error because a Variant can be *everything* - including an error. However, this will not solve your problem - the value couldn't be found.

If you change your code to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` and the value can't be found, you will get a Runtime error 1004 ("Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class"). You can use VBA error handling (On Error...) to catch that error, but the reason itself is the same: Your value was not found in the lookup list, and there is nothing we as the community can do for you...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have changed the result to a variant and added the error handling and get the message that the value is not found within the range even though it definitely is. I'm not sure what the other possibilities are tbh as I'm new to VBA but if you cannot work it out, I definitely won't

Comment: Again, this is not a VBA problem, it's a problem with your data. The same VLookup used as formula in your sheet would return the same result (displayed as `"#n/a"`). Also double check that you are looking into the correct sheet (`Sheets("ContractCode")`) and the correct Range (`"A1:B132"`)

Comment: That's the thing, the vlookup works fine anywhere else and returns everything correctly, has to be the vba

Comment: VBA `Application.VLookup` is just a wrapper to the native VLookup and you can be sure it works. Is your code failing for all sheets or only for one? Sure you don't have a typo in the sheet name? Sure you are referring to the correct Lookup list? Sure you want to deal with the Active Sheet?

Comment: no typo, I have now changed the name in Codes just to make it shorter and easier, still not luck. It is is the correct lookup list (A1:B132) and I am dealing with the active sheet to turn that into the pdf and the vlookup is only for the name of the newly created pdf

Comment: @Nafees please share a screenshot of your sheet including the sheet tab, and at least the portion of the list where the sheet name is found.

Comment: @BigBen have attached the pictures, sheet names and where the sheet name is in my list

Comment: Your screenshots are nearly unreadable, but what I can see is that the workbook doesn't contain any sheet named ContractCode. As you run the code for the ActiveSheet and accesses the ContractCode-Code without qualifying the workbook, I assume the ActiveSheet is not the one you want to deal with. Which can be easily checked with the debugger.

Comment: @NafeesRabbani are your codes in column A numbers, or numbers stored as text? What is the exact VLOOKUP formula you used that works?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but add this code to debug. It will print out a list of all 132 values in your list, and tell you `True` or `False` whether they match your lookupvalue:

```
' Perform the VLOOKUP
lookupvalue = sheetname

Dim rg As Range
For Each rg In Sheets("ContractCode").Range("A1:A132")
    Debug.Print lookupvalue, rg, lookupvalue = rg
Next rg

lookupresult = Application.VLookup(lookupvalue, Sheets("ContractCode").Range("A1:B132"), 2, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen yes I completely agree, but the point here is just to `debug.print` out the full lookup list so he can see which value is being looked up, and why it doesn't match what he thinks it matches.

Comment: @kevin Not sure I understand what you want me to do because when i put this code after my perform the vlookup, I still get a mismatch error

Comment: @NafeesRabbani as explained "It will print out a list of all 132 values in your list, and tell you True or False whether they match your lookupvalue". Did you scroll through that list of 132 values and check that it shows the correct list of values? And the correct `lookupvalue`? Did you find the one that you expected to match, and see that it said `False`?

Comment: When i input this code and run, it just gives me a mismatch error, where are the 132 values supposed to be listed ??

Comment: In the Immediate window in the VBA editor. If it is not shown, click View > Immediate Window

Comment: Thanks, the first sheet name is 670 and that comes up as true, the rest are obviously false

Comment: First line is true but `Vlookup` result is still an error? Try changing the debug code to this: `Debug.Print lookupvalue, rg, lookupvalue = rg, rg.Offset(0,2)`. Now it should give you a 4th column that should show what the result of the `Vlookup` would be

Comment: Have just seen your updated question and I can reproduce the error if the sheet name is a number, and the list of values are numbers. However, I do not get the error if I `Dim lookupValue As Variant`. Can you leave it as `Variant` for the rest of the testing

Comment: I tried to change the debug code but it does not add a 4th column. I have also changed the lookupvalue to a variant but get the same error. Also now that i have changed it to variant, the result of the debug has changed to false

Comment: Sorry that debug line should have been `.Offset(0,1)`, but doesn't matter, I think the problem is related to your sheet names being number values. Try changing the lookup code to this `lookupResult = Application.VLookup(CInt(lookupValue), Sheets("ContractCode").Range("A1:B132"), 2, False)`, any luck?

Answer (score -1):

sheetName is a useless variable so I would remove it.

To address your question, you could either do:

```
lookupResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookupValue, Sheets("ContractCode").Range("A1:B132"), 2, False)
```

or just search through the sheet on your own:

```
Dim i as Long
Dim endRow as Long: endRow = 132
For i=1 to endRow
   If Cells(i,1).value = lookupValue Then
      lookupResult = cells(i,2).value
      goto BREAK
   End If
Next i
BREAK:
```

Comment: When i add the worksheet function part, it will give me class error

Comment: **(a)** For the first part:  If `Application.VLookup` fails, `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` will also fail. See for example https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/application-vs-application-worksheetfunction.584913. **(b)** For the 2nd part: Why do you use `goto BREAK` instead of `Exit For`?  **(c)** Please don't use unqualified ranges. `cells(i,2)` will fail when the sheet containing the lookup ("ContractCode") is not the active sheet.

Comment: @FunThomas Do you have any suggestions for my issue above ?

Comment: @NafeesRabbani What do you want to do if the name of the active sheet cannot be found in your lookup table?

Comment: @FunThomas That is what I am trying to workout, the name of the sheet is definitely in the lookup array but the vba code is not working that out

Comment: The name of the sheet is definitely **not** in the lookup array. Maybe it looks like it is, but there must be a difference. Trailing (or sometimes leading) spaces are often a reason.

Comment: @FunThomas No spaces or anything, it is exactly the same, I just think my code is wrong as the debug highlights the lookup result line

Comment: @NafeesRabbani when all else fails, try using `=VLOOKUP(...)` as a worksheet formula. You'll still get an error, but it may help identify the issue.

Comment: @BigBen the vlookup works fine in the worksheet

Comment: Then likely `ws.Name` is not what you think it is. Check for trailing spaces on the sheet name. Check the `Len` of it as well. It would also be best to specify the parent workbook for `Sheets("ContractCode")`.

Answer (score -1):

- Replace `VLOOKUP` with a `For` loop.
- Enhance efficiency by loading the lookup table into an array if needed, especially for large tables.
- Assuming that cell `A100` has the sheet name, you can run the code to show validation information. Alternatively, check its value in the Local Window.

```vb
' ... your code
' Get the sheet name
sheetName = ws.Name

' Perform the VLOOKUP
Dim c as Range
For Each c in Sheets("ContractCode").Range("A1:B132")
    ' *** for testing
    If c.Row = 100 Then ' modify as needed
        Debug.Print c.Value, Len(c.Value)
        Debug.Print sheetName, Len(sheetName)
        Debug.Print sheetName = c.Value
        Stop ' Check the value of variables in VBE [Local Window]
    End If
    ' *** 
    If c.Value = sheetName Then 
        lookupResult = c.Offset(0,1).Value
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If Len(lookupResult)=0 Then 
    MsgBox "Can't find " & sheetName
    Exit Sub
End If

' ... your code
```

Comment: @Nafees Rabbani have you tried the code?